# Sector Variable?

Tags: collegescorecard

I am searching through the data files and dictionary using a variety of keywords (sector, public, etc.) and can't seem to find the Sector variable from IPEDS.

Control is there, as are a few clues to derive a level (Carnegie for some, highest degree), or I can just match from another database using UNITED, but please tell me I'm missing something!

Otherwise, great launch on the programming and UX side from 18F!

Answer (score 1):

The sector variable from IPEDS is not included in the raw Scorecard data sets. The 2-year and 4-year distinction presented in Scorecard represents predominant degree (PREDDEG) which identifies the type of degree that the school primarily awards (This is different than IPEDS)

Comment: Thanks Brian. Do you think that it will be added down the road? There are already 1700+ fields, what is one more.

The Scorecard Technical Paper even has a whole section on sector-level analysis, which underscores its importance (pg 34, https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/UsingFederalDataToMeasureAndImprovePerformance.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, will consider this in future iterations. In the meantime, you can match the sector variable by pulling IPEDS data and matching on the unit ID.  In case it's helpful, I just did a custom IPEDS query that you can use, just enter this code Guest_31961139026 into this page here: http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/LoadSession.aspx